# PHP Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. 
Godaddy server Error show ?

Comment: uncomment the extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini file on Godaddy server and restart the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to enable the following extension in php.ini:

```
extension="php_intl.dll"
```

Once done, please restart the server.

Comment: server godaddy how to restart

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the extension disabled in your php config file. Have a look at your php.ini file which is normally located somewhere in /etc directory. Search for the extension and check if the line is disabled by ";". If so, remove the ";" and you should be good to go. It might be that you have to restart your webserver like Apache/Apache2, but I am not familiar with Godaddy, so apparently I am not sure if you can restart it or how it is handled.